# Run a php file using URL in crontab

Tags: cron, cpanel

I want to run a php file from a url using cron tab.
I am using a webhosting and i give a command like that

```
9 11 9 2 * wget -O /dev/null http://www.domainname.com/cronfile.php
```

but it does not work please tell me why this not work.
I think this command must run a "cronfile.php" and i do not want to recive any email from cron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
9 11 9 2 * wget -O /dev/null 'php -f /path/to/cronfile.php'
```

or add to 'cronfile.php'

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

and give it running permissions:

```
chmod +x 'cronfile.php'
```

See the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) for full details of running PHP from the command line

**UPDATE 1**

Any chance there's a problem with the path? if you try and edit the file `vi path/to/file.php` can you open it? if so, try and run manually `php -f /path/to/cronfile.php`, did you gen an error? if not, add to your php file the following:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

**UPDATE 2**

I think you are a bit confused. **Why are you running it via URL? What are you trying to achieve?**

By 'executing' http://www.domainname.com/cronfile.php the file won't run locally, PHP Server-side HTML embedded scripting language, which means that when you'll run http://www.domainname.com/cronfile.php vi your local crontab, the file will run on the remote server (www.domainname.com) and not locally, same as if you'll open this URL in a browser.

As long as it's a static script it's better to run it locally. Once you're running via URL you'll be vulnerable to [code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) using [URL hijacking](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typosquatting&ei=NS8ZUY-hOoHbtAbiiYHACQ&usg=AFQjCNGR_k1RGETIXPDq6HKE00BM_J2C3A&sig2=MZLTCYcS4RDL8TUFqQk3Ew&bvm=bv.42080656,d.Yms). I advise you to read about it.

**UPDATE 3**

to add parameters use [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php):

```
php -f /path/to/cronfile.php hello_world
```

and in the php file:

```
echo $argv[0];
```

Comment: i did not get any error it works via `path/to/file.php` but dose not work via url.

Comment: In my php file there is some parameters.which i want to give value of these parameters in url like this.
`http://www.domainname.com/cronfile.php?para1=value1&para2=value2`
if i run it locally then i am not able to provide the values of these parmeters.This is the reson i want to run `cronfile.php` via URL.

Comment: due to some reason i need to run cron via url.
I coding my php file with respect to URL i did not want to change my coding.So, I need something which run my locally file through URL.
Can it is possible if yes,Please guide me.

Comment: is the site at http://www.domainname.com is running apache? what happens when you're opening it in the browser? do you see the php matrkups?

Comment: then no, you can't. As i said, php is a server side scripting language, meaning it will run on the server, not locally.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether your target page is local. If it is, you can use the command `php5 /path/to/php/file.php`. If it is not, the wget approach is correct, although I'd call it like so: `/usr/bin/wget --quiet --output-document=/dev/null http://www.server.com/page.php`. Hope this helps.
(possible duplicate of [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/96427/cron-job-to-open-a-webpage))

Comment: I can use both command `path/to/file.php` and `/usr/bin/wget --quiet --output-document=/dev/null http://www.server.com/page.php` both are not work.

Comment: I can use `php -f /path/to/file.php` it work well but this one is not work `/usr/bin/wget --quiet --output-document=/dev/null http://www.server.com/page.php`.